# while evaluating conditional (argoProj.stdout.find('xcore') != -1): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'

Tags: ansible, roles

**Workflow:**

1. got stdout from the first task using register variable
2. used the same values to check whether it contains "xcore" or not
3. if not, another task to create a new project on Argo CD using Ansible roles.

```yaml
---
- name: Create a new Argo CD project
  hosts: localhost
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
  - name: Checking project list {{proj_name}}
    shell: |
        argocd proj list | grep -i xcore
    register: argoProj

  - name: checking xcore value present if not create a project
    shell: |
         argocd proj create xcore

    when: argoProj.stdout.find('xcore') != -1
```

Getting below error.

```
output: 
argocd proj list | grep -i xcore
xcore          2 destinations                 18 repos                               <none>         <none>                        <none>          disabled
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks

I got correct output from registered variable used in debug

```yaml
- name: Create a new Argo CD project
  hosts: localhost
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
  - name: Checking project list {{proj_name}}
    shell: |
        argocd proj list | grep -i testpjct

    register: argoProj
  - debug: var=argoProj
```

> ok: [localhost] => { "argoProj": { "changed": true, "cmd": "argocd
> proj list | grep -i testpjct\n", "delta": "0:00:00.787347", "end": "2021-02-03 08:32:04.982026", "failed": false, "rc": 0, "start": "2021-02-03 08:32:04.194679", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "testpjct

Comment: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'argoProj.stdout == \"xcore\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (argoProj.stdout == \"xcore\"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ubuntu/excore/xcore-role/tasks/argocd-project.yml': line 12, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: checking xcore value in above stdout\n    ^ here\n"}

Comment: print the `argoProj` registered variable using the debug module, and see what you are getting.

Comment: i'm got correct output from registered variable used in debug

Comment: *
ok: [localhost] => {
    "argoProj": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "argocd proj list | grep -i testpjct\n",
        "delta": "0:00:00.787347",
        "end": "2021-02-03 08:32:04.982026",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-02-03 08:32:04.194679",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "testpjct

Comment: @Haridvpsk Please do not spread necessary info to answer your question over volatile comments. Edit your question instead. While you do that, please also take some time to get accustomed to the editor and format your code and errors correctly. Thanks.

Comment: sure i'm reediting my code and do pasting same

Comment: Add the error to your question as well. As I am seeing no reason for it to fail. The error already shared in the first comment doesn't seem to fit in with your implementation.

Comment: Your debug output is cut in the middle (not complete). You talk about an error but you show the result of the shell command. Please fix.